# Unable to remove border color on focus for pagination dots

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to remove the unwanted greyish and blue color that pops up on the focus. It doesn't seem to be appearing in the css somehow.

[image]

```
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet swiper-pagination-bullet-active" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 3"></span>
```

Here's the css:

```
.swiper-pagination-clickable .swiper-pagination-bullet {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet  {
    width: 12px !important;
    height: 12px !important;
    margin: 4px !important;
    background-color:  $carousel-pagination-page-bg-color !important;
    opacity: 0.6 !important;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
    background-color:  $carousel-pagination-page-bg-color-hover !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: try add `outline: 0!important;` to `.swiper-pagination-bullet {}`

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Yea saw that swiperjs was adding an outline. Thanks though.

Comment: no problem, friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like swiperjs was adding an outline, `outline:none` worked.